# Validation messages not fade away from cascading controlls MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

It's quite an annoying problem. I have a form bound to the model. There are some required fields. Most of them are dependent on one dropdown. If I load the page and directly click on Submit button, all validation messages are getting displayed. Now If I select a value from A drop-down, "B" and "C" drop-down's value getting filled automatically. But the validation messages for bot are still visible. Any help is appreciated.

Below is my html:

```
<div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.A, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)this.ViewBag.Breed, "Select Breed", new { @class = "width100" })</div>
<div class="eror_msg">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A)</div>

<div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.B, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select Skin Color", new { @class = "width100" })</div>
<div class="eror_msg">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.B)</div>

<div>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.C, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select Eye Color", new { @class = "width100" })</div>
<div class="eror_msg">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C)</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#A').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
     success: function(data){
     // building html to bind to B and C
     $('#B').html(htmlforb).val(2).trigger('change');
     $('#C').html(htmlforc).val(5).trigger('change');       
  }
    });
  });
});
```

When I select the value from A, B and C's value get filled and selected automatically based on some conditions and business logic. Both's `change()` event got triggered. But only A's validation message fade away. B and C's validation message is still visible.

For your information, this view is a partial view.

Comment: Do you have some code to demonstrate the problem? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to show your code, but assuming your 2nd dropdownlist is populated using jquery, then you need to trigger the 2nd dropdownlist `.change()` event.

Comment: Why you are not checking whether dropdown has selected value or not, when person is click on submit button itself?

Comment: I am triggering change() event. But not working. Message is still visible.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please have a look at sample code.

Comment: All your have shown is the Razor code. How are the dropdown lists for `B` and `C` populated? Where is the code you claim triggers the `.change()` event?

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Added jQuery code. I had tried with .change() but didn't worked then tried trigger('change'). Still not working.

Comment: A couple of options to try - `$('#B').html(htmlforb).val(2).trigger('blur');` and `$('#B').html(htmlforb).val(2).valid();`